# How often, and how promptly, do airports have to renumber runways because of magnetic pole drift?

Tags: runways, magnetic-variation

*This question was prompted by [this answer to another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/34774/8736) by Jamiec.*

As the magnetic poles drift (usually pretty unpredictably), runway numbers become inaccurate. As noted in the linked answer, this has resulted at the very least in the renaming of the 15/33 runways at Madrid to 14/32.

How often does this happen, and at what point is it no longer reasonable for pilots to make the corrections necessary to make a smooth landing, requiring a renaming of the runways?

Comment: Runway renumbering. I've seen charts showing magnetic declination variation in the past, and it's certainly constant!

Comment: My experience (in the Florida area) is that magvar shifts enough to require runway number changes every 10 years or so -- it is location dependent.  The local magvar has shifted about 2.5 deg over the last 25 years.

Comment: @Jules: That's [not constant](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Earth_Magnetic_Field_Declination_from_1590_to_1990.gif)

Comment: My previous comment should say every 10 years at one of the local airports.  Since the Runway numbers are to the nearest 10 degrees (+/- 5 deg), it depends on the actual runway alignment relative to the transition point.  For some airports, it may not happen for another 80 or 90 years.

Comment: @mins I think the original comment was deleted -- "constant" referred to the variation in declination, not the state of the declination

Comment: In the style of the duplicate; short answer: when its appropriate, medium answer: when it has drifted >3 degrees, long answer: read Lnafziger great answer :)